# Why am I getting negative outputs when I run my method to print prime factors of a user input?

Tags: c#, list, methods, logic-error

So, I'm writing a method that takes a user input and prints all of its prime factors. It works, except it's giving me a negative number at the end of every list. What is causing this??

```
static void PrimeFactors(int userInput)
{
    // create a variable which is a new version of userInput that can be manipulated by the method
    int input = userInput;
   
    // declare a new list which will contain all of the factors of the user input. 
    var factors = new List<int>();


    // While the input is greater than 1, if input mod counter is equal to 0,
    // add counter to factor list and set input value to input / counter
    // if input % counter != 0, break and start the for loop again
    
    for(int counter = 1; input >= 1; )
    {
        if(input % counter == 0)
        {
            factors.Add(counter);
            input = input / counter;
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;
        }
        
    }
    // display the prime factors 
    foreach (int factor in factors)
    {
        Console.Write($"{factor}  ");
    }
}
```

When I input 90, I get 1, 2, 3, 5, -3. When I input 31, I get 1, 31, -1. When I input 500, the output is 1, 2, 5, 10, -5. You get the point.

I know my code is not complete in terms of filtering ONLY prime factors, but I want to address these negative numbers before refining things to make sure only prime numbers get on the list.

Comment: You need to change the loop check to `input > 1` because when you get to one is when you want to exit.

Comment: @juharr Note that, with the current code, changing the loop check to `input > 1` will work only for some inputs, such as 31, but not others such as 90 (since `input` only goes down to 3) and 500 (since `input` only goes down to 5). A simpler example is if the initial input is 12, then `counter` being 2 reduces `input` to 6, then `counter` being 3 causes `input` to become 2. However, `counter` will keep increasing so it'll be more than 2, but `input` will stay at 2 until after overflow occurs. I explain about this in some detail in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is due to numeric overflow. In particular, your code doesn't have an appropriate exit condition, such as checking if `counter > input`, in your loop code of

```cs
    for(int counter = 1; input >= 1; )
    {
        if(input % counter == 0)
        {
            factors.Add(counter);
            input = input / counter;
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;
        }
        
    }
```

For positive counter values where `input % counter == 0` is true, then `counter` is less than or equal to `input`. Thus, the line of code `input = input / counter;` will have `input` still be a positive integer, so the `for` loop check of `input >= 1` will always succeed. This means, since `counter` is a signed 32-bit integer, it'll continue increasing until it reaches [Int32.MaxValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue?view=net-8.0) = 2147483647, i.e., 2^31 - 1. It then overflows with the high bit set to become the smallest negative integer value which is [Int32.MinValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.minvalue?view=net-8.0) = -2147483648, i.e., -2^31. After that, it'll continue increasing until it gets to the negative of the `input` value, in which case the line `factors.Add(counter);` will add this negative value, and `input = input / counter;` will cause `input` to become -1, thus finally causing the loop to terminate.

Thus, with your example of 90, the positive factors of 1, 2, 3, 5 multiply to 30, leaving a factor of 90 / 30 = 3 as the `input` value, which is why the final entry is -3. Similarly, with 31, there's just the factor of 31, so `input` becomes 1, resulting in a final list value of -1. Finally, with 500, the factors of 1, 2, 5, 10 multiply to 100. Thus, there's a remaining factor of 5, and so a final entry of -5 is in your list.

A relatively simple fix is changing the `for` loop condition check of `input >= 1` to `counter <= input` instead. Also, although your code is not complete, as you state, one small suggestion is that since the `for` loop always increments `counter`, instead of doing that in two separate code lines as you do now, you can remove those lines and add that increment as the increment/decrement part of the `for` loop, e.g., have that line instead be

```cs
    for(int counter = 1; counter <= input; counter++)
```

---

Regarding your stated goal of finding and reporting on the prime factors, in addition to what I suggest above, there's a relatively simple set of changes you can make to your loop to accomplish this. In particular, just start with `counter` at 2 (since 1 is not a prime) and insert this line

```cs
            while (input % counter == 0)
```

above this line

```cs
                 input = input / counter;
```

This works because the first time the `if` condition works, `counter` will be the smallest prime factor of `input`. Then the `while` loop will remove all instances of that prime factor. Thus, each next value of `counter` which is a factor can't be composite since each of the `counter` prime factors would have been removed earlier. Thus, the code will only be finding and adding prime factors to the `factors` list.

Below is some sample code

```cs
        static void PrimeFactors(int userInput)
        {
            // create a variable which is a new version of userInput that can be manipulated by the method
            int input = userInput;
           
            // declare a new list which will contain all of the factors of the user input. 
            var factors = new List<int>();

            // While the counter is less than equal to the input, if input mod counter is equal to 0,
            // add counter to factor list and then, as long as input mod counter is 0,
            // set input value to input / counter.
            
            for(int counter = 2; counter <= input; counter++)
            {
                if(input % counter == 0)
                {
                    factors.Add(counter);
                    while (input % counter == 0)
                        input = input / counter;
                }
            }
            
            // display the prime factors 

            Console.Write("Prime factors of {0}: ", userInput);
            foreach (int factor in factors)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}  ", factor);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] testUserInput = {90, 31, 500};
            for (int i = 0; i < testUserInput.Length; i++)
            {
                PrimeFactors(testUserInput[i]);
            }
        }
```

which produces the output of

```
Prime factors of 90: 2  3  5
Prime factors of 31: 31
Prime factors of 500: 2  5
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this thorough explanation!! I really appreciate that you took the time to break this down for me. Seriously, I learned a ton from this answer!

Answer (score 0):

the problem come from this line:

```
if(input % counter == 0)
```

if input = 31 and counter >= 32 => input % counter always not equal 0. The counter increase until it gets overflow and flipped to the minimum number. For instance:

```
int a = int.MaxValue;
int b = 1;
int c = a + b; // c will be -2147483648
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, note that largest possible prime for `userInput` factor is `Sqrt(userInput)`:

```
userInput = p * p
```

Knowing this fact we can implement

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

private static IEnumerable<int> DistinctPrimeFactors(int value) {
  if (value <= 1)
    yield break;

  // Special case for even numbers
  if (value % 2 == 0) {
    yield return 2; 

    while (value % 2 == 0)
      value /= 2;
  }

  int n = (int) (Math.Sqrt(value) + 0.5);

  for (int divisor = 3; divisor <= n; divisor += 2)   
    if (value % divisor == 0) {
      yield return divisor;

      do
        value /= divisor;
      while (value % divisor == 0);

      n = (int) (Math.Sqrt(value) + 0.5); 
    }

  if (value > 1) 
    yield return value;
}
```

Then you can `Join` the prime factors:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(" ", DistinctPrimeFactors(500)));
```

Output: (`500 == 2 * 2 * 5 * 5 * 5`)

```
2 5
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZjxOI4)